# How to configure hdmi0 and hdmi1 togheter for raspberry pi4?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, monitor, touchscreen, hdmi

I'm quite new on the raspberry pi world, but not on linux.
I have bought a screen 7 inch with touchscreen. It works well, but if I attached another screen on HDMI 1 (tv monitor), that screen is on but only black display (not disconnected). If I connect the tv monitor to HDMI0 and 7inch display on HDMI1, the tv monitor works fine but the touchscreen sometime is black or it has the image of raspberry pi (I attached a photo).
The touch work fine, but I can see the mouse move in the other screen. If I replace the HDMI cable, I will see the screen in the touchscreen and tv monitor black.
The touchscreen is this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07 ... UTF8&psc=1
I have changed the /boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

the lines below I tried to remove it, but same behaviour, majority of the time screen black on the hdmi1 and work perfectly on hdmi0

```
hdmi_edid_file:1=1
hdmi_edid_filename:1=edid.dat
hdmi_force_hotplug:1=1
```

someone has any suggestion?
thank you in advance for the reply.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, just used another SDCARD and flash again. It worked immediately